# Change URLs in default Wordpress slider to relative from absolute

Tags: filters, pages, url-rewriting, urls

I would like to change the URLs in my Slider, which was built with the default Wordpress Slider admin, to relative from absolute.

I note that when I select a image from the Media Library the URLs are absolute, so this may be where my problem lies. I would like these to be relative.

I have had a look at:
https://www.webhostinghero.com/how-to-insert-relative-image-urls-in-wordpress/

and in particular this code:

```
function switch_to_relative_url($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt)
{
    $imageurl = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, $size);
    $relativeurl = wp_make_link_relative($imageurl[0]);
    $html = str_replace($imageurl[0],$relativeurl,$html);

    return $html;
}
add_filter('image_send_to_editor','switch_to_relative_url',10,8);
```

...however it has no effect on the URLs in my slider.

Is there a way to change all media library URLs to relative? I am on Wordpress 4.8.3.

Comment: It may not be wise to change all media to relative URLs. See [this question & answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85106/16121) for insight.

Comment: Also, I'm not clear on what you mean by *default WordPress Slider admin*, since, to my knowledge, there *is* no "default WordPress Slider".

Comment: You have a plugin or included functionality in your theme that has created that slider.